# Javascript property checked on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checked

I don't know why but I just had such a difficult time to find browser support on this property. Which browsers support `inputCheckbox.checked` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually find good compatibility information on MDN.  For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility

That says you are ok as long as you don't care about Internet Explorer 1.0

Comment: That compatibility table mentions the `checked` HTML attribute not the `checked` DOM property. They are different things, which is why I didn't mention it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every browser that supports JavaScript and forms.